# React Router useHistory in component that is imported from outside React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a component library with React. In the project I want to make use of the useHistory hook in my own Link component. Whilst developing the library I have a CRA app in which I can test the components. I do this by importing the components from the dist folder which sits outside the CRA. My file structure looks like this:

```
CRA
  -- public
  -- src
    -- features 
      -- feature // Trying to import from here '../../../dist'
    -- routes
    -- etc

dist
src
```

All UI components from my library, when imported from `'../../../dist'` sit within the `Router` component correctly but thee history object is undefined. I suspect this is down to how I am importing them but  would like  to know if there is anyway around this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think doing like that can make the import missing all the dependencies you need in your component library. Try use npm link or yalc instead when its come to local package import.

Comment: @JakeLam thx for the reply, if I understand you correctly, I would run npm link from the component library root to the CRA instance of react router?

Comment: Yes, you can gg search for how to use npm link